# Creating a scroll able windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, autoscroll

I have a windows form wherein i am displaying all the tables,figures etc. But, the problem is that even though i set the auto scroll property to true, the form hence created doesn't have a scroll bar.

Comment: The scrollbar(s) get shown only __when needed__. Push a Control over the border and they will show up!

Answer (score 1):

Write in your `form_load` and make sure you have not changed it any where.

```
 private void yourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
 }
```

Verify it by re sizing your form else scroll bar will not be visible.